# Polymorphism on a REST service

Tags: oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am trying to clean and refactor my service code which currently looks like this-

```
public void generateBalance(Receipt receipt) {

if (receipt.getType().equals(X) && receipt.getRegion.equals(EMEA)) {

// do something to the receipt that's passed 

} else if (receiptType.equals(Y)) {

// do something to the receipt 

} else if (receipt.getRegion.equals(APAC) {
// call an external API and update the receipt
}....

...
// finally

dataStore.save(receipt);
```

Basically there's a bunch of conditionals that are in this main service which look for certain fields in the object that is being passed. Either it's the type or the region.

I was looking to use this design pattern- https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html
However, I am not sure how this would work for a service class. Currently my REST handler calls this particular service. Also how can I do polymorphism for both the "receiptType" and "region"?

Is there a way I can just do all the updates to the receipt once in different services, then finally save the receipt at one location? (maybe a base class?) I am really confused on how to start. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes should have the same behaviour, then it becomes pretty simple to use polymorpism.  The pattern is called as [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Let me show an example.

At first we need to use `enum`. If you do not have `enum`, then you can create a method which will return enum value based on your conditions:

```
if (receipt.getType().equals(X) && receipt.getRegion.equals(EMEA)) // other 
     // code is omitted for the brevity
```

So `enum` will look like this:

```
public enum ReceiptType
{
    Emea, Y, Apac
}
```

Then we need an abstract class which will describe behaviour for derived classes:

```
public abstract class ActionReceipt
{
    public abstract string Do();
}
```

And our derived classes will look this:

```
public class ActionReceiptEmea : ActionReceipt
{
    public override string Do()
    {
        return "I am Emea";
    }
}

public class ActionReceiptY : ActionReceipt
{
    public override string Do()
    {
        return "I am Y";
    }
}

public class ActionReceiptApac : ActionReceipt
{
    public override string Do()
    {
        return "I am Apac";
    }
}
```

Moreover, we need a factory which will create derived classes based on enum. So we can use [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) with a slight modification:

```
public class ActionReceiptFactory
{
    private Dictionary<ReceiptType, ActionReceipt> _actionReceiptByType =  
        new Dictionary<ReceiptType, ActionReceipt>
    {
        {
            ReceiptType.Apac, new ActionReceiptApac()
        },
        {
            ReceiptType.Emea, new ActionReceiptEmea()
        },
        {
            ReceiptType.Y, new ActionReceiptY()
        }
    };

    public ActionReceipt GetInstanceByReceiptType(ReceiptType receiptType) =>
        _actionReceiptByType[receiptType];
}
```

And then polymorpism in action will look like this:

```
void DoSomething(ReceiptType receiptType) 
{
    ActionReceiptFactory actionReceiptFactory = new ActionReceiptFactory();
    ActionReceipt receipt = 
        actionReceiptFactory.GetInstanceByReceiptType(receiptType);
    string someDoing = receipt.Do(); // Output: "I am Emea"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create some helper method which will return `enum` value based on
your logic of `region` and `receiptType`:

```
public class ReceiptTypeHelper
{
    public ReceiptType Get(ActionReceipt actionReceipt) 
    {
        if (actionReceipt.GetType().Equals("Emea"))
            return ReceiptType.Emea;
        else if (actionReceipt.GetType().Equals("Y"))
            return ReceiptType.Y;

        return ReceiptType.Apac;
    }
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    ReceiptTypeHelper receiptTypeHelper = new ReceiptTypeHelper();
    ReceiptType receiptType = receiptTypeHelper
        .Get(new ActionReceiptEmea());

    ActionReceiptFactory actionReceiptFactory = new 
        ActionReceiptFactory();
    ActionReceipt receipt =
        actionReceiptFactory.GetInstanceByReceiptType(receiptType);
    string someDoing = receipt.Do(); // Output: "I am Emea"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. One thing- I mentioned that the receiptType is different than the region. I want to handle particular logic for a given receiptType and a region separately. How can I do that? With this approach I think I would have to create a separate class for each region and receiptType. Essentially, there are two enums I have to deal with

Comment: @mistermims please, see my updated answer